# Get the full Play Store on Tecno M7

Tags: google-play-store, tecno

How do I get Play Store on my Tecno M7 phone? It didn't come preinstalled.

Answer (score -1):

To get the Play Store on a device that doesn't ship with it, just [download the APK for it](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/).

This should work on any Android phone, though you may need to get an earlier version if you're software version is too old for the current version of the Play Store.

Comment: Play Store app cannot work by itself without flashing the Play Services framework as system apps.